# AWS-Vault not regconizing nested profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, credentials, credential-manager

My aws config file looks like this

```
[profile foo]
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/foo
region = eu-west-2
sts_regional_endpoints = regional

[profile foo-1]
source_profile = foo
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/foo
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/ReadOnly
region = eu-west-2
include_profile = default

[profile foo-admin]
source_profile = foo
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/foo
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/admin
region = eu-west-2
include_profile = default

[profile bar-role]
source_profile = fooadmin
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::333333333333:role/Role1
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/foo
region = eu-west-2
```

When I run `aws-vault exec foo-1 -- ANY AWS COMMAND` or `aws-vault exec foo-admin -- ANY AWS COMMAND` it work just fine.

But when I run `aws-vault exec bar-role -- ANY AWS COMMAND` it fails with the error `aws-vault: error: No credentials found for profile bar-role`

If I try `aws-vault add bar-role`, it prompts for cred which  don't have, as I'm assuming a role.

Is there a way to add nested profiles into aws-vault?

Comment: That's essentially the same as the example config shown at the [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) site. It ought to work if they've documented it.

Comment: It might potentially be something to do with your version of aws-vault.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed using 'unset AWS_VAULT' to fix this for myself.